# How do I make a scatter plot with rectangle markers?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have 5 same length long vectors (V1,V2,Color,xboundaries,yboundaries), and I would like to plot them like scatter(V1,V2,Color,'filled',rectangle(xboundaries,yboundaries)).I have used the function image, but the xboundaries and the yboundaries are not constant and I have to use a for loop, which in my case is not good, as it takes a long time to process the data. The problem is that matlab does not recognize rectangle as a valid MarkerType. Is there a way I can make this possible?

Comment: A square is not sufficient?

Comment: The `scatter` function's [documentation on markers](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatter.html#inputarg_markertype) (also `doc scatter` in your Command Window). It sounds like you may be trying to use markers and `scatter` for something beyond their intended purpose. Some sort of statistical plot?

Comment: siliconwafer: A square is not enough, since each cell has a different size. holchler: Sorta, I'm trying to display data in a faster way. I just found out the the path function may do the trick I need. p = patch('Faces',faces,'Vertices',verts,'FaceColor',Color); where verts are points, and faces connect these points into a shape. Color will be the corresponding colors for each face